# Customised driver for touchpad

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling

I need **One finger** scrolling and **"corner tap"** for my touchpad. (Because I am physically disabled).

On my Lenovo V310 notebook with Elan touchpad AND any wireless keyboard with touchpad or "trackpad" I can buy (I prefer Logitech or Apple).

The old Synaptcs driver (on old HP notebook) worked perfectly for me.
But every nowday hardware driver is ONLY multitouch.

Can I use old Synaptics driver somehow? (to make it working with Elan touchpad or Logitech)

Is there **any 3rd party** driver, or just application which can handle gestures and transform it as a scroll?

Comment: A driver designed to support a Synaptc touchpad CANNOT work with an Elan touchpad.